# USB 2.0 devices not work on my mac only USB 3.0 Working

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I have a MacBook Pro 15" Unibody (Mid 2012).

The USB ports stopped working a while back; i.e.: the computer would no longer recognize any of USB devices. They are all USB 2.0 devices (external drive, Flash drive, etc.).

I did some testing and confirmed that it does indeed not recognize any USB 2.0 devices. the computer works just fine with any USB 3.0 devices that I've tested it with.

I've already tried all the usual quick fixes: reset SMC, reset PRAM, etc.
What’s the problem is? Is it a hardware or software issue?

Comment: Did you happen to see this related webpage? https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/411486/weird:+USB+2.0+devices+not+recognized,+but+USB+3.0+devices+work+ok